# Executing Hive Scripts in Impyla

Tags: python, hive, impyla

The examples I've seen for Impyla are for executing command line queries,

i.e. the equivalent to running

```
hive -e 'select * from my_db.my_table'
```

Is there functionality in Impyla to be able to run something like :

```
hive -f create_hive_table.hql \
     -hiveconf my_db=db1 \
     -hiveconf my_table=tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just connect to Hive using the default HiveServer2 port.

Default ports:
For Impala -> `21050`
, For Hive -> `10000`

- No Security

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='myhost', port=10000, auth_mechanism="NOSASL")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show databases')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

- LDAP

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='myhost', port=10000, auth_mechanism='LDAP', password='ldap_pass', user='user', use_ssl=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show databases')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```